Build a neural network to diagnose my digestive disorders
Unfortunately, I'm having some GI problems that are mostly reactions to food. Following my doctor's advice, I was keeping a diary, but it seems the problem is more complex than "you eat this, you feel bad 2 hours later" as combinations of foods that I eat in the same meal and even the order of meals might affect the result. So, I was thinking that before going completely mad from trying to analyse it myself :) I could train a machine learning algorithm or a neural network to help.
I have some experience as a developer, but never dealt with ML directly, so I'd use some help to choose the best algorithm/model.
I was planning on feeding the model with

a list of (time, [list of foods]) where each food is just a name
a separate list of (time, [array of symptoms]) where each symptom would be an integer number on 0-3 scale.

and expecting the model to predict symptoms from foods
Could you advise me on the best algorithm/model to choose for this task? Does the data need some preprocessing?

If it seems more complex than "you eat this, you feel bad 2 hours later", how will a model that predicts 'symptoms from foods' be useful?
Think carefully about what useful model predictions would look like. What information should they provide you with? E.g.

Statements like: "Symptoms increase when you eat peanutbutter sandwiches on days where you are stressed, and more so when you had little exercise and ate more than 85 grams of non-chicken meat the previous day." You'll need an enormous amount of records and design a very complex model to get such answers, with reasonable precision and accuracy.
Statements like "Wholewheat sandwiches do not increase symptoms." "Peanutbutter does not increase symptoms." "Wholewheat sandwiches combined with peanutbutter increase symptoms". This can be done if you recorded data accordingly, and use a tree ensemble or (elastic net) linear regression with some interactions included. However, this option sounds like "you eat this, you feel bad 2 hours later", but you write it is more complex than that.

Database design (data selection and pre-processing) is going to be more critical than the type of algorithm used to analyze it. Modeling the effect of time may likely be critical, and may be difficult to capture accurately. You'll probably need to keep track of quantities; how you are going to record the quantities and types of foods your eat? E.g., are you going to record 'number of sandwiches'? Or weight, brand, ingredients of the sandwiches? Your insights on what the relevant variables are may change over time, requiring you to restart and recollect your database.
You do not need neural nets, because this looks like it will be tabular data, furthermore neural nets tend to require huge amounts of data to work well. Elastic net regression and tree ensembles (random forest or xgboost) would be first to try on my list. But incorporation of time structures may be critical, so methods for time series may be much more relevant.
This is experience-based opinion. As a statistician and Type-I diabetic, I've tried similar for understanding my blood glucose levels. The relevant variables are fewer and better known for T1D than for many GI problems, but level of unpredictability may be similar. I gave up soon, realizing I got more insight and actionable knowledge from keeping a diary for a week, and reviewing it with a diabetes nurse, then repeating this procedure from time to time. The complexities of the modeling task may drive you mad sooner than keeping a diary and reviewing it with a health professional. Either approach will require time, patience and trial-and-error.

Thank you! Very valuable comment! What I expect is: I enter what I'm about to eat - it gives me probabilities for symptoms. Since everything is more-or-less periodic in GI tract, I'd hope 2-3 days of data would complete a single GI-cycle. And keeping this diary for 2-3 weeks might be enough for some insights. Would you agree? Since I'm currently on a diet, there's not a plethora of different foods I can put into my meals, but it seems certain combinations are causing the symptoms, and, sometimes, the time of day I eat them. For example, I tend to avoid meat in the first half of a day.

If after 2-3 weeks I see that predictions are too imprecise, I could go for some simplifications, for example, lowering the amount of possible labels: instead of putting in rice, barley, etc, I'd just use cereal.

Keeping this diary for 2-3 weeks could certainly provide you with some insight. (Of course, if symptoms are simply unpredictable, there is little insight to be gained.) How many records will suffice will strongly depend on the strenght of association between foodtypes and symptoms, which is yet unknown. The more categories you use, the more records you will likely need for reliable estimation and prediction. But at the same time, very specific categories may actually be necessary; this all depends on the pattern of association, which is as yet unknown. All the best, hope you find insights!
